# Access file from ModelForm of an Inline within ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm relatively new to django so what I'm trying to do may be obviously wrong but please bear with me. :-)

I have a `ModelForm` with a `FileField`:

```py
class ModelBForm(ModelForm):
file = forms.FileField()

class Meta:
    model = ModelB
    fields = ['some_additional_field']
```

which I include in an `Inline`:

```py
class ModelBInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = MyForm
    model = ModelB
```

which I set in a `ModelAdmin`:

```py
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ModelBInline]
```

which I include in my `admin.py`:

```py
admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelAAdmin)
```

Now I need to access the file of `FormB`, because in this file are values which I need for the creation of my `ModelB` Objects, which belong to `ModelA`.

Adding single `ModelB` objects via the `Inline` is to cumbersome, that's the reason I wanted a file import.

I know that if you have `FormB` directly included in `ModelAAdmin` I could override the `save_model` to access the file:

```py
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ModelBForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        file = request.FILES['file']
        # do stuff with file
```

But since the values in the file are `ModelB` values rather than `ModelA` values I'd like to input the file in the `Inline` and not the `ModelAdmin`.

Experimenting with overriding `save_related` and `save_formset` always gave me a `MultiValueDictKeyError`, even though I see my file in the `Files` section of the `Request Information` in the Traceback.

So my **question**: Where/How can I access a file of a form which is included in an inline, used in a ModelAdmin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution now but it feels a bit like a hack.
The *"hacky"* part is that I have to save the id of ModelA in the `save_model` method, so that I can access it from `save_formset`.

```py
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    modela_id = 0
    inlines = [ModelBInline]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        additional = instances[0].some_additional_field
        modela = ModelA.object.get(id=self.modela_id)
        file = formset[0].cleaned_data['file']
        # use file, additional and modela to create modelb objects

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        self.modela_id = obj.id
```

Feel free to post answers which solve my problem in a more elegant way!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `save_related` would be the place to do that.

You shouldn't access the file via the request though. If it's in the form, you should access it via `form.cleaned_data['file']`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! However if I try that I get `KeyError`. Maybe I have to go for the formsets?